# Correct way of sending error information, but code still runs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, error-handling

What is the right way to send error information to my backend. I have the following example in my head.

The code is running, but at somepoint a value is broken. At this point I want to throw some error information to my backend and my application shouldn't stop. It would send me the error and continue.

Comment: by using ajax to send the error to the back end?

Comment: I don't understand

Comment: It's good to delete the question if you don't need an answer.  But feel free to leave it up if you still need one.

Answer (score 1):

Don't think you should have code that breaks in production, but you can do a try catch block.

```
function exampleFunction() {
    try {
        untestedFunction();
    } catch(err) {
        sendErrorToBackend(err)
    }
}
```

If the `untestedFunction()` breaks, it'll end up calling `sendErrorToBackend` which you could use to send the error log to your server.